# Best implementation of DFS

Tags: python, algorithm, global-variables, graph-theory

I am implementing DFS algorithm on Python3, my actual code is

```
def util_DFS(G, i, startTime, globalStartTime):
   """
   Util function used in DFS
   :param G: (networkx.DiGraph) Graph on which will be applied the DFS algorithm
   :param i: Integer representing the vertex from which DFS will be applied
   :param startTime: global variable containing an array recording the time needed to reach each vertex
   :param globalStartTime: global variable recording the number of nodes visited
   """        
   startTime[i] = globalStartTime
   globalStartTime += 1
   for j in G.neighbors(i):
       if startTime[j] == -1:
           util_DFS(G, j, startTime, globalStartTime)

        
def DFS(G, i):
   """
   :param G: (networkx.DiGraph) Graph on which will be applied the DFS algorithm
   :param i: Integer representing the vertex from which DFS will be applied
   """     
   startTime = np.zeros(len(G), dtype=np.int64) - 1
   globalStartTime = 0
   util_DFS(G, i, startTime, globalStartTime)
   return startTime
```

The code works fine and gives the results that we wait from it, but I was wondering if there is a better method to code DFS, a method that doesn't require two function as I have done.

Note that the second function `DFS` is just a wrapper of `util_DFS`. I needed such a wrapper because the variables `startTime` and `globalStartTime` need to be global

Comment: On a side note, if the graph is disconnected, this won't work

Comment: Can you explain more please,  is it due to the fact that the recursion will continue infinitely if some arc is not reached ?

Comment: I have just checked for a disconnected graph, and it is working fine

Comment: Every node won't be reached if the graph is disconnected. Only the component which contains the starting node(where you start the dfs) will be explored

Comment: yes of course, that's normal. I mean this is the purpose. I won't consider this "not working". the algorithm is supposed to work like this.

Comment: Since you have working code and are asking for "better", this question is more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you @trincot I will post it there. Should Idelete this question ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs on codereview.